# Can random numbers be generated with set gaps between them?

Tags: xcode, random, nsmutablearray, draw

I have the code below

```
NSMutableSet * numberSet = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:10];
while ([numberSet count] < 10 ) {
    NSNumber * randomNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:( (arc4random() % (190-10+1)) + 10 )];
    [numberSet addObject:randomNumber];
}
```

This generates a set of 10 random numbers that I use for plotting 5 points in a view. These points then have circles drawn around them.

```
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(a, b) radius:6 startAngle:1 endAngle:10 clockwise:YES] fill];
```

Is there an easy way to make sure the numbers aren't within a certain gap of one another. For example I don't want two circles to cross one another. I'm thinking of using quite a few if statements but wondering if there is an easier way of achieving the same thing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code generates 10 circles with radius 10 that does not intersect each other. I agree with bames53 that the best approach is to check if a generated circle intersects previously generated circles.

```
// Seed random generator
srand(time(NULL));  

const float radius = 10;
const int numberOfCircles = 10;

// Defines the area where the center of the circles are allowed 
const float min_x = 0 + radius; 
const float max_x = 320 - radius;
const float min_y = 0 + radius;
const float max_y = 367 - radius;

NSMutableSet * nonInterSectingCircles = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:numberOfCircles];

while ([nonInterSectingCircles count] < numberOfCircles ) {

    float x_new = randomNumber(min_x, max_x);
    float y_new = randomNumber(min_y, max_y);

    BOOL intersectsExistingCircle = NO;

    for (NSValue *center in nonInterSectingCircles) {
        CGPoint centerPoint = [center CGPointValue];
        if (distance(x_new, centerPoint.x, y_new, centerPoint.y) < radius * 2) 
            intersectsExistingCircle = YES; 
    }

    if (!intersectsExistingCircle) [nonInterSectingCircles addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(x_new, y_new)]];

}
```

The following functions are used:

```
float distance(float x1,float x2, float y1, float y2) {

    float dx = (x2 - x1);
    float dy = (y2 - y1);

    return  sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

float randomNumber(float min, float max) {

    float random = ((float) rand()) / (float) RAND_MAX;
    random = random * (max - min);
    return min + random;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably going to have to keep track of the numbers generated so far and use those to help generate each next random number. For example, if you want a gap of 5, generate the first number between MIN and MAX, add 5 to it, and generate the next number between that and MAX. A little extra code to wrap around to the beginning of the range if you pass MAX, and you're good to go.

Another alternative would be to break up the range of possible numbers into N subsets and generate one number in each sub-range. So, for a range from 1 to 100, you could generate one number in 1 to 10, the next in 15 to 25, the next in 30 to 40, etc., ensuring a roughly even distribution but retaining some randomness.

The exact approach you want to use is going to depend on what kind of distribution you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to generate the random numbers and discard the ones that fall in those gaps. This can probably be done reasonably efficiently if you keep a sorted sequence of the numbers, and before inserting a new number you check if the next highest and lowest numbers are sufficiently far away.

Also you might consider using the C++ `<random>` library, because that provides you with distributions that will probably do a better job than you producing your own distribution (given that the example code is `(arc4random() % (190-10+1)) + 10`).